# How to get the title attribute and innerHTML from a <a> link tag in robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, xpath-2.0

I have an HTML link

```
<a class="product-name" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=7&amp;controller=product" title="Printed Chiffon Dress" itemprop="url" style="user-select: auto;">Printed Chiffon Dress</a>
```

I want to get the value of the title or innerHTML "Printed Chiffon Dress"

```
        Verify Best Sellers functionality
        Click Link  //ul[@id='home-page-tabs']//child::li[2]//a
        @{links}=  Get WebElements  //div[@class='right-block']//h5//a
        ${cnt}=    Get length    ${links}
        Log  There are ${cnt} lines in the description
    
        FOR    ${a}  IN  @{links}
              ${text}=  Get Text    ${a}
              Log  ${text}
        END
```

Comment: Why do you think this code isn't working? Does it throw errors? Is it logging the wrong text?

Comment: @BryanOakley It is working , It is not throwing any error , But the text that is coming is null

Answer (score 1):

Try `Get Element Attribute` from [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute)

```
 FOR    ${a}  IN  @{links}
              ${text}=  Get Element Attribute    ${a}   title
              Log  ${text}
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to debug whether you get any output in @{links} if yes, then try following code

```
FOR ${a} IN @{links}
    Log to Console  ${a.text}
END
```

Comment: This keyword is also Not working

Comment: First, you need to debug whether you get any output in @{links} if yes, then try the code that I updated above.